# expressjs redirect to angular route not initiating app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, redirect

I have following nodejs app.js

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.get('some_api', routes.someApi);

app.use(function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});
```

and angularjs app.js and index.html

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/login/login.view.html',
    controller: 'loginCtrl'
  })

angular
    .module('app')
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', config]);
```

====================

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-view></div>
  <script src="/app.js"></script>  
</body>

</html>
```

from expressjs api i am redirecting to '/' like:

```
module.exports.some_api = function (req, res, scope) {
   res.redirect('/');
};
```

But after redirection i see lots of errors in console saying angular not defined.

Looks like angular is not getting trigger.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: where is your angular app initialization code. something like this: var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

Comment: @GauravSrivastava in same hierarchy of app.js. I have added above.

Comment: angular.module('app')  should be angular.module('appliedBio')

Comment: @GauravSrivastava: thats just  a typo.

Comment: @GauravSrivastava If i simple run app its working fine. The problem starts only when i call res.redirect('some_api') or res.redirect('/') from inside expressjs api.

Comment: how can you use node to redirect angular app, node is on server and angular is on client. You can pass the response from the node and cache it from angular then redirect based on response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151369/discussion-between-maverickosama92-and-gaurav-srivastava).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i called the angular route directly like this from expressjs api:

```
module.exports.some_api = function (req, res, scope) {
   res.redirect('/#/summary');
};
```

And it works.